Surface cutting through a cone in tikz
I have the walls of a cone and a surface cutting through this cone. I can only get either the cone behind the surface or in front of it, but not that the surface cuts properly through it.
I get this:

The code:
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage{tikz,pgfplots}     
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest} 
\begin{document} 
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.9]
\pgfplotsset{colormap={black}{gray(0cm)=(0); gray(1cm)=(0)}}
\begin{axis}[
        axis line style={->},
        no markers,
      grid=major,              
      major grid style=dotted, 
      colormap name=black,            
      samples=30,              
      view={120}{30},          
      domain=0:1,
      domain y=-1:1,
      xmin=-1.5,
      xmax=1.5,
      ymin=-1.5, ymax=1.5,
      zmin=0.5, zmax=1.5  
    ]
    \addplot3[surf, z buffer= sort,  mesh/interior colormap={blueblack}{color=(black) color=(red)},colormap/blackwhite]({x*cos(deg((y+1)*pi))-1.5},{x*sin(deg((y+1)*pi))-1},{x});
    \addplot3[surf, z buffer= sort,  mesh/interior colormap={blueblack}{color=(black) color=(blue)},colormap/blackwhite, domain=-1.5:1.5,domain y=-1.5:1.5, samples=2, samples y=2, opacity=0.5, shader=interp,]({x)},{y},{1-x/6-y/6});
    \draw[ultra thick,blue] (-1.5, -1.5,1.5) -- (-1.5,1.5, 1) -- (1.5,1.5, 0.5) -- (1.5,-1.5, 1) --cycle;
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture} 
\end{document}

I have tried various ways, but nothing seems to work so the plane visibly cuts through the cone.
Does anyone have an idea how to do this?

\documentclass[tikz, border=1cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}
\begin{document} 
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
view={120}{40},          
xmin=-1.5, xmax=1.5,
ymin=-1.5, ymax=1.5,
zmin=0.5, zmax=1.5,
grid=major,
major grid style=dotted,
]

\addplot3[
surf,
z buffer=sort,
mesh/interior colormap name=hot,
colormap/blackwhite,
domain=0.5:1.3, samples=20, variable=h,
y domain=0:360, samples y=37, variable y=a,
x filter/.expression={z<1-x/6-y/6?x:3*cos(a)/(sin(a)+cos(a)+6)},
y filter/.expression={z<1-x/6-y/6?y:3*sin(a)/(sin(a)+cos(a)+6)},
z filter/.expression={z<1-x/6-y/6?z:1-x/6-y/6},
] ({(h-0.5)*cos(a)},{(h-0.5)*sin(a)},h);

\addplot3[
surf,
ultra thick,
blue!50!black, faceted color=blue,
fill opacity=0.5,
domain=-1.5:1.5, samples=2,
domain y=-1.5:1.5, samples y=2,
] ({x},{y},{1-x/6-y/6});

\addplot3[
surf,
z buffer=sort,
mesh/interior colormap name=hot,
colormap/blackwhite,
domain=0.5:1.3, samples=20, variable=h,
y domain=0:360, samples y=37, variable y=a,
x filter/.expression={z>1-x/6-y/6?x:3*cos(a)/(sin(a)+cos(a)+6)},
y filter/.expression={z>1-x/6-y/6?y:3*sin(a)/(sin(a)+cos(a)+6)},
z filter/.expression={z>1-x/6-y/6?z:1-x/6-y/6},
] ({(h-0.5)*cos(a)},{(h-0.5)*sin(a)},h);

\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture} 
\end{document}



That works a treat. Thank you!
